# How to change an HTML Link Value using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow, textchanged

I have an HTML page where I want to change Image & Link with at regular interval of time.
I have following code in Head Tag :

```
<sctipt>
var slideimages=new Array()
var slidelinks=new Array()
var text = document.getElementById('slidetext')

function slideshowimages(){
  for (i=0;i<slideshowimages.arguments.length;i++){
  slideimages[i]=new Image()
  slideimages[i].src=slideshowimages.arguments[i]
  text.innerHTML = textChange.aruguments[i]
  }
}

function slideshowlinks(){
  for (i=0;i<slideshowlinks.arguments.length;i++)
  slidelinks[i]=slideshowlinks.arguments[i]
}

function gotoshow(){
  if (!window.winslide||winslide.closed)
    winslide=window.open(slidelinks[whichlink])
  else
    winslide.location=slidelinks[whichlink]
    winslide.focus()
}
</script>
```

And Following Code in Body Tag :

```
<script>
slideshowimages("D:/Search/images/back1.jpg", "D:/Search/images/back2.jpg", "D:/Search/images/back3.jpg","D:/Search/images/back4.jpg","D:/Search/images/back5.jpg","D:/Search/images/back7.jpg")
slideshowlinks("http://wsabstract.com", "http://dynamicdrive.com", "http://java-scripts.net","http://stackoverflow.com","http://superuser.com","http://serverfault.com")
textChange("wsaabstract","dynamicdrive","java-script","stackoverflow","superuser","serverfault")


var slideshowspeed=3000
var whichlink=0
var whichimage=0

function slideit(){
  if (!document.images)
    return
    document.images.slide.src=slideimages[whichimage].src
    document.getElementById('slidetext').innerHTML=text.value
    whichlink=whichimage

  if (whichimage<slideimages.length-1)
    whichimage++
  else
    whichimage=0
    setTimeout("slideit()",slideshowspeed)
}
</script>
```

The Images are changing regularly but only when I have not used the text label that is "slidetext" (which is also hyperlink). But, Using text label, image & text become steady. So, what should be modification to change image & text at regular interval.

Comment: 1) *Please* use semicolons after each statement and indent your code properly, as your current indentation doesn't imply what's happening. 2) Don't feed `setTimeout` a string, but a function. 3) What does `textChange` do?

Comment: what does the actual HTML look like?

Comment: Where's the "textchange" function?

Comment: textChange is not a function but is only an array from which I have to fetch element & have to display it as a hyperlink.

Comment: @Sarang: Why did you roll back my corrections of typos and (especially) indentation? It's confusing to look at *this*. Moreover, `textChange` isn't an array, but a function call, the way you use it. It should read something like `var textChange = [ … , … ];`

Comment: @Marcel: oh! sorry, it is function & not array. So, I think I have to create that function in which I have to code the change of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

text.innerHTML = textChange.aruguments[i]

Normal the fault in your code ?

Comment: There were other typos, too. The script wouldn't function at all with them.